# JavaScript date conversion for a current date fetched from a device?

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I am fetching current date from a device. It returns the date as `10-11-17`
I want to convert it to `10-11-2017` using JavaScript.

I tried `setUTCFullYear()` and Moment.js but I didn't get any solution.

Comment: try to use data('m-d-Y');

Comment: If the device is returning a string, then you can't call date methods on it. Why not just `s.replace(/(\d\d-\d\d-)(\d\d)/,'$120$2')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `moment` you need to use the `Parse` method with a format string:

`var d = moment('10-11-17', 'DD-MM-YY')`

And the `Format` method:

`console.log(d.format('DD-MM-YYYY'))`

---

The [docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) have a lot of information.

Answer (score 1):

try pure javascript method

```
   let date = new Date('10-11-17');
   date.toLocaleDateString();
```

Comment: Using the built-in parser is likely the worst option. How do you know if the string is d/m/y, m/d/y or y/m/d?

Comment: let it be date object from device, toLocaleDateString() still works,

Answer (score 1):

you can just do this without moment.js.

```js
format_date = function( date )
{
 date = new Date( date );
 var year = date.getFullYear(),
 month = date.getMonth() + 1, 
 day = date.getDate();
 if ( month.toString().length == 1 ) month = "0" + month;
 if ( day.toString().length == 1 ) day = "0" + day;
 return  month + "-" + day + "-" + year;
}
var result = format_date( "10-11-17" );
console.log( result );
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is convert a string 10-11-17 to 10-11-2017, then why not:

```js
console.log('10-11-17'.replace(/(.*-)(.+)/,'$120$2'));
```

Which avoids all issues with parsing and formatting a date without using any libraries. It also doesn't care if the format is dd/mm/yy or mm/dd/yy.